# Could not load either windows 10 or Ubuntu 16 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I was running my laptop fine with windows 10 and decided to install ubuntu alongside windows 10. I created an installation USB using Rufus and shrinked my C drive to free up 250GB of space. Went through the installation process with mostly all default options and selected install ubuntu alongside windows 10 on the installation screen which installed Ubuntu on sdb . After finishing the installation selected restart and pulled the USB out as that is set as my first boot device. Currently I could not boot into either one of them. I can see Ubuntu and windows 10 listed on the grub menu. Also if I go into recovery option and select resume I am able to boot Ubuntu. Could you please help me fix this so I can boot into either OS?

Comment: Did you turn off Windows fast start up/hibernation? Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12 after UEFI/BIOS screen, but before grub2 loads. What brand/model system? What video card/chip. What version of Ubuntu? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  Hibernation off: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 0):

the best dual boot using Virtualbox 
click here to download : https://www.virtualbox.org/

while you are downloading....

watched this ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncA85gRAJxk